# Get total SUM of 3 columns and multiple records from second table

Tags: mysql, sql

Morning,

I have 2 tables with a relationship being box_id.

The first table is structured as:

```
box_id    | box_name | length | width | depth
---------------------------------------------
1         | box_1    | 30     | 30    | 20
```

It has details of a storage box ie. name, width, length depth etc.

The second table has an inventory of whats in that box)...

```
id    | bid | product_name | prod_length | prod_width | prod_height
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | 1    | phone case  | 12          | 6          | 2 
2     | 1    | watch       | 8           | 8          | 7        
3     | 1    | perfume     | 16          | 10         | 14
```

Using SQL im looking to get the details of the box including **(length * width * depth / 10)** of that box to get its total volume capability, plus to total volume consumed by the products in the box.

Results

```
box_id | box_name | volume  | volume remaining
----------------------------------------------
1      | box_1    | 1800 cm3 | xyz cm3
```

Here is the SQL i have so far..

```
select box_name, width, length, depth, (width * length * depth / 10) AS totalVolume from storage...
```

Im not sure how to get the inventory details and see whats remaining or consumed.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The volume of the contents would come from a query like this:

```
select bid, sum(prod_lengt * prod_width * prod_height) as volume
from inventory
group by bid;
```

You can use a `join` to compare the volumes:

```
select b.*,
       (length * width * height) as box_volume,
       bi.volume as inventory_volume
from boxes b left join
     (select bid, sum(prod_length * prod_width * prod_height) as volume
      from inventory
      group by bid
     ) bi
     on bi.bid = b.id;
```

You can subtract the two or take a ratio.  But don't over-interpret the results.  It is a hard problem to figure out how much "inventory" can fit in a "box" based on the dimensions.  The sum of the volumes is not sufficient for answering this question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just testing your script now... could you please explain what you mean by Its a hard problem to figure out how much inventory can fit in a box etc. Im assuming if a box has 1000m3 of volume i could fit almost that amount of products.  or have i missed somthing. Regards

Comment: @shanej . . . This is a hard problem and you are not going to solve it in SQL (or if you do, it would be really, really impressive).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem.

Comment: Oh I see... im was going to have a cut of point for each storage box of around 20-25 percent, just so each box has a bit of breathing space and not 'over full' or 'overcrowded'. Thanks again.

Comment: @shanej . . . If you are trying to solve a real-world problem, I would suggest that you learn about bin-packing.